# hide textbox control using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide textbox control using javascript or jquery.I have used javascript

```
document.getElementsByName('Custom_Field_Custom1').style.display="none";
```

java console shows me this error :

```
document.getElementsByName('Custom_Field_Custom1').style.display="none" is undefined.
```

Please help me

Comment: Notice the plurality in the method `getElementsByName`. That indicates we are being returned an array. Loop it or pull the first item from it.

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByName` returns an array. You either want to use an ID and call `getElementById`, or use `getElementsByName('Custom_Field_Custom1')[0]`.

Comment: It returns a NodeList, not an Array. They are only superficially similar.

Answer (score 2):

`$('input:text')` would select all textboxes in the page.

Hence, `$('input:text').hide();` would hide all your textboxes.

If you need to hide a single textbox you can give it an id, as in `<input type="text" id="Custom_Field_Custom1" />`

`$('#Custom_Field_Custom1').hide();` would then hide that single one.

Comment: ok,but why I am getting document.getElementsByName('Custom_Field_Custom1').style.display="none" is undefined. ?

Comment: That would match `<Custom_Field_Custom1>` elements, which aren't allowed in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByName` returns a NodeList not an HTMLElementNode. It doesn't have a style property, so you get the error because `undefined.display` isn't allowed.

Loop over the NodeList as if it was an array.

Comment: thanks I have used document.getElementsByName('Custom_Field_Custom1')[0].style.display="none";

Answer (score 1):

Well seems all the possible answer comes here. I just simplified the answer :

for change CSS with jquery use following code :

```
$('#Custom_Field_Custom1').css('display','none');
```

For hide the text box with jquery use following code :

```
$('#Custom_Field_Custom1').hide();
```

In both case remember one thing here **"Custom_Field_Custom1"** must be **id** of the textbox.